# How to activate a certain profile in a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

Suppose we have 3 projects, A,B,C

A,B are dependent on C. C has 2 profiles defined in its POM, say profile1, profile2.

How do I make sure, when A is using C, profile1 is activated and when B is using C, profile2 is activated.

Comment: Are these three separate projects, or modules in a multi-module project? Please edit your question and add actual pom files to illustrate exactly what you mean.

Comment: Please also explain exactly what you are actually trying to achieve, as there may be a better way.

Comment: If is used as a dependency than the simple answer is: No. Because you are consuming the dependency not the build pom. The other question is: Why do you need a profile to be activated? And you see based on your description that you are using too much profiles it become complicated...